# magento2.2.3 - Can't create directory

Tags: magento2, ubuntu

I am using magento 2.2.3 in ubuntu 16.04. I have transferred a server copy to my local pc. I am having following error

```
RuntimeException: Can't create directory /var/www/html/new_utshob/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/. in
[Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor] in
/var/www/html/new_utshob/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:115 Stack trace: #0
/var/www/html/new_utshob/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php
(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Framewo...') #1
[internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader-
>load('Magento\\Framewo...') #2 [internal function]: 
spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Framewo...') #3 
/var/www/html/new_utshob/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19
): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\\Framewo...') #4
/var/www/html/new_utshob/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runt
ime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader-
>getConstructor('Magento\\Framewo...') #5 
/var/www/html/new_utshob/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/
Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime-
>getParameters('Magento\\Framewo...') #6
/var/www/html/new_utshob/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.p
hp(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer-
>create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #7
/var/www/html/new_utshob/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(232):
Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...',
Array) #8 /var/www/html/new_utshob/index.php(38):
Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\\Framewo...') #9 
{main}
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Give permission using below command.

```
chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/new_utshob
```

Comment: Now having another problem. Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: WeltPixel\OwlCarouselSlider\Block\Slider\Custom
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class WeltPixel\OwlCarouselSlider\Block\Slider\Custom does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Give file permission to  your `generated/` `pub/` `var/` folders

`sudo chmod -R 777 generated/ pub/ var/`

Answer (score 0):

you just need to check your webserver username
mostly its www-data

```
sudo chown -R www-data generated var
sudo chmod -R 777 generated var
```

Note: Update www-data with your webserver username

this should fix your problem